# Hiding The Data

Tags: java

I want to mask few columns based on the criticality of that column, so that once i give these files to my team, they should see masked or encrypted value for development purpose.

I have a file(excel,csv, tsv or anything) which contains 7 columns, columns can increase or decrease based on the file.

```
name,creditcard,lastname,personal_data,address,city,state
ajay,1234567899999993,jat,1234,pune,pimpri,maharashtra
naresh,9876543210547863,mantri,2674,pune,timpri,maharashtra
sanjay,2452352352525523,hatra,3224,pune,wakad,maharashtra
sarabjit,12235667889768,rango,3114,pune,timpri,maharashtra
```

i need to mask few column data based on the number of alphabet it has.
Say for example i want to mask creditcard number,personal_data. after masking the output file should contain the same number of columns as per the input file.
But the 2 or 3 or what ever columns are masked , it should contain same no. of charaters but may be in different format like (creditcard number is 16 digits so it should contain exact 16 but can contain alpha numeric in the output file.

Request you to provide a java code or some routine or logic to build this complex situation.

I need to give these kind of multiples files to my members so that they cannot see important information which are masked but still work on those columns for further development purpose.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have tried to check on google for options, for this particular situation, iam unable to find a code.

Comment: You've defined the logic.  Let us know when you've written the code to mask important data fields.

Comment: You have to define the requirements.  For instance, if you only store and display credit card numbers, you can chnage them all to 16 question marks.  If you verify the checksum or determine which bank issued the credit card, you'll have to generate credit card numbers.  Totally up to you and your requirements.

Comment: `$(document).on("change", "#personal_data", function(){
    if($(this).val() == "1234") {
 then
        $("#personal_data").attr("data-mask","1@#$");
 }

if($(this).val() == "creditcard") {
 then
        $("#creditcard").attr("data-mask","0000-0000-0000-0000");
 }

    }else{
        $("#Cnumber").attr("data-mask", "9999-9999-9999-9999");
    }
});
`

Comment: this is what iam trying to achieve...

Comment: You need to add additional information and code to the question, not as an easily missed comment. Not to mention the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to read and parse each line of the input file, obfuscate the contents of some particular field(s), then write the line out to the output file.

To obscure some particular fields, you can hash the fields and replace them with the base-64 encoding of the resulting hashcodes, truncated to the same length as the original field data.

But if all you want to do is just obscure some fields, replacing them with randomly generated characters should be sufficient.

It sounds like the only trick is knowing *which* fields to obscure.

**Addendum**

Here is a method that generates a random string of the same length as a source string:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomGenerator
{
    static private long     s_seed =  123;
    static private Random   s_rnd =   new Random(s_seed);

    public static String genRandomString(String src)
    {
        char[] dst = new char[src.length()];

        for (int i = 0;  i < dst.length;  i++)
        {
            char ch = src.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                ch = (char) (s_rnd.nextInt(10) + '0');    // Random char [0-9]
            else if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch))
                ch = (char) (s_rnd.nextInt(26) + 'A');    // Random char [A-Z]
            else
                ch = '?';
            dst[i] = ch;
        }
        return new String(dst);
    }
}
```

Test program available at: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/p7MYiZ).

Comment: Yes David, i know the fileds which needs to be masked, for the above example, i need Credit card and personal_data to be masked; since Credit card is always 16 digits, i want theme to be masked with alph-numeric and same for personal based on the datatype of that column. Iam looking out to achieve it with a Java code may be. still wondering how to start with the code.

Comment: the code should take input file and generate output file. as per the above code, its not like that..can you please guide me on that..